# creating a search tool for Access listbox

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-access-2007

I have a listbox with many fields in a form and I'm trying to create a search function that searches for partial strings inside it.

```
Private Sub SearchBox_Change()
    Me.DataView.RowSource = "SELECT RowSrcString FROM MechDataFiltered WHERE " & _
    "MechDataFiltered.* LIKE " & Chr(34) & Me.SearchBox.Text & "*" & Chr(34) & " "
End Sub
```

`RowSrcString` is a  string of field names (from MechDataFiltered) that changes depending on other filters. I think my problem is in the 3rd line; `MechDataFiltered.*` is for "all" instead of "any". What should I change to make it search in each individual field?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at some [search criteria](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html) samples on Allen Brown's site. It's fairly advanced from a programming standpoint, but he is one of the experts in the industry and I have used tips from his site on numerous occasions.

Allen demonstrates how to use search criteria from multiple input fields to dynamically build a query (filter) expression that returns the results that I think you are looking for.

He has some sample databases you can download to try out the various techniques.

Hope that helps!